# Having Issue on Getting Row Data Into an Array From jQuery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Can you please take a look at **[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/6egzjjtf/)** and let me know why I am not able to get selected row into an array? 
his the code I am using to get the data:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrLoadDb = [];

    $('#example').DataTable();

    $('.add-row-db').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('tr').find('td:not(td:first, td:last)').each(function () {
            arrLoadDb.push($(this).text());
            console.log(arrLoadDb);
        });
    });
});
```

but I am getting this result instead of an array!

[image]

Comment: that result **is** an array

Comment: Your `arrLoadDb` variable is an array. Just you have to type outside of loop and get your expected output. http://jsfiddle.net/6egzjjtf/1/

Comment: another possible fundamental error is that with each click `arrLoadDb` is added to, never cleared - which looks wrong

Answer (score 0):

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/6egzjjtf/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arrLoadDb = [];

    $('#example').DataTable();

   $('.add-row-db').on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
       arrLoadDb = []
    $this.closest('tr').find('td:not(td:first, td:last)').each(function(){
    arrLoadDb.push($(this).text());

   });
       console.log(arrLoadDb);
  });


} );
```

For each time when you click on button it will search for all the column values except fist and last column.

for each button press we need clear the array